# Plesk WWW prefix

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, subdomain, plesk, domain-aliasing

I'm having trouble with the WWW prefix for my domain.  Whenever I goto the domain http://mydomain.com I get the correct index page.  However, using the www prefix, I get the plesk default index page.

I have a subdomain called *.mydomain.com that points to it's parent httpdocs directory which is required for a url rewrite to our salespeople's profile pages (see below).  There is also an alias for a completely different domain for mydomain.com (as you will see in last_httpd.include)

I can't seem to narrow it down.  Commenting out the url rewrites in .htaccess didn't seem to work, neither did removing the *.mydomain.com subdomain.

I've provided what I can to perhaps give some insight to how things are setup.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
The www record in DNS is set as an A(host) record.
```

Here is the contents of my .htaccess file for the main domain.  The domain name edited for obvious reasons...

```
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x- javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/agents/agent.php?agent=%1 [P,L]
```

My last_http.include file for the main domain in /var/vhosts/www/mydomain.com/conf/

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
#
#IF YOU REQUIRE TO APPLY CUSTOM MODIFICATIONS, PERFORM THEM IN THE  FOLLOWING FILES:

#/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/conf/vhost.conf
#/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/conf/vhost_ssl.conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:443 >
    ServerName "mydomain.com"
        ServerAlias  "www.mydomain.com"
                        ServerAlias  "ipv4.mydomain.com"
                UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias  "mydomainalias.com"
    ServerAlias  "www.mydomainalias.com"
        ServerAlias  "ipv4.mydomainalias.com"


<IfModule mod_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup "mydomain" "psacln"
</IfModule>

    ServerAdmin  "admin@mydomain.com"

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs"
    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics/logs/access_ssl_log plesklog
    ErrorLog  "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics/logs/error_log"



<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/web_users"
</IfModule>

    ScriptAlias  "/cgi-bin/" "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/cgi-bin/"



    Alias  "/plesk-stat" "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics"
    <Location  /plesk-stat/>
        Options +Indexes
    </Location>
    <Location  /plesk-stat/logs/>
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    Alias  /webstat /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics/webstat
    Alias  /webstat-ssl /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics/webstat-ssl
    Alias  /ftpstat /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics/ftpstat
    Alias  /anon_ftpstat /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics/anon_ftpstat
    Alias  /awstats-icon /var/www/html/awstats/icon


    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/certQ69DPXb

SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/etc/php.ini

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/etc/php.ini
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 16777216
</IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs>

<IfModule mod_perl.c>
    <Files ~ (\.pl$)>
        SetHandler perl-script
        PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
        Options ExecCGI
        allow from all
        PerlSendHeader On
    </Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
php_admin_flag engine on

# General settings
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/:/tmp/"
php_admin_flag display_errors off
php_admin_flag log_errors on
php_admin_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
# Performance settings
php_admin_value memory_limit 64M
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 256M
# Additional directives

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_admin_flag engine on

# General settings
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/:/tmp/"
php_admin_flag display_errors off
php_admin_flag log_errors on
php_admin_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
# Performance settings
php_admin_value memory_limit 64M
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 256M
# Additional directives

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_python.c>
    <Files ~ (\.py$)>
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler
    </Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <Files ~ (\.fcgi)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    </Files>
</IfModule>

        SSLRequireSSL

        Options -Includes +ExecCGI

    </Directory>



<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Domain statistics"
    AuthUserFile "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/pd/d..httpdocs@plesk-stat"
    require  valid-user
</Directory>
Alias /error_docs /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/error_docs
ErrorDocument 400 /error_docs/bad_request.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error_docs/unauthorized.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error_docs/forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error_docs/not_found.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error_docs/internal_server_error.html
ErrorDocument 405 /error_docs/method_not_allowed.html
ErrorDocument 406 /error_docs/not_acceptable.html
ErrorDocument 407 /error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html
ErrorDocument 412 /error_docs/precondition_failed.html
ErrorDocument 414 /error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html
ErrorDocument 415 /error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html
ErrorDocument 501 /error_docs/not_implemented.html
ErrorDocument 502 /error_docs/bad_gateway.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error_docs/maintenance.html

    Include "/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/file_sharing.conf*"



</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>

<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80 >
    ServerName "mydomain.com"
        ServerAlias  "www.mydomain.com"
                        ServerAlias  "ipv4.mydomain.com"
                UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias  "mydomainalias.com"
    ServerAlias  "www.mydomainalias.com"
        ServerAlias  "ipv4.mydomainalias.com"


<IfModule mod_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup "mydomain" "psacln"
</IfModule>

    ServerAdmin  "admin@mydomain.com"

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs"
    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics/logs/access_log plesklog
    ErrorLog  "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics/logs/error_log"



<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/web_users"
</IfModule>

    ScriptAlias  "/cgi-bin/" "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/cgi-bin/"



    Redirect permanent /plesk-stat https://mydomain.com/plesk-stat
    Redirect permanent /webstat https://mydomain.com/webstat
    Redirect permanent /webstat-ssl https://mydomain.com/webstat-ssl
    Redirect permanent /ftpstat https://mydomain.com/ftpstat
    Redirect permanent /anon_ftpstat https://mydomain.com/anon_ftpstat
    Redirect permanent /awstats-icon https://mydomain.com/awstats-icon


    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine off
    </IfModule>

SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/etc/php.ini

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/etc/php.ini
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 16777216
</IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs>

<IfModule mod_perl.c>
    <Files ~ (\.pl$)>
        SetHandler perl-script
        PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
        Options ExecCGI
        allow from all
        PerlSendHeader On
    </Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
php_admin_flag engine on

# General settings
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/:/tmp/"
php_admin_flag display_errors off
php_admin_flag log_errors on
php_admin_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
# Performance settings
php_admin_value memory_limit 64M
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 256M
# Additional directives

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_admin_flag engine on

# General settings
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/:/tmp/"
php_admin_flag display_errors off
php_admin_flag log_errors on
php_admin_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
# Performance settings
php_admin_value memory_limit 64M
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 256M
# Additional directives

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_python.c>
    <Files ~ (\.py$)>
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler
    </Files>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <Files ~ (\.fcgi)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    </Files>
</IfModule>


        Options -Includes +ExecCGI

    </Directory>



<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/statistics">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Domain statistics"
    AuthUserFile "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/pd/d..httpdocs@plesk-stat"
    require  valid-user
</Directory>
Alias /error_docs /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/error_docs
ErrorDocument 400 /error_docs/bad_request.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error_docs/unauthorized.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error_docs/forbidden.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error_docs/not_found.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error_docs/internal_server_error.html
ErrorDocument 405 /error_docs/method_not_allowed.html
ErrorDocument 406 /error_docs/not_acceptable.html
ErrorDocument 407 /error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html
ErrorDocument 412 /error_docs/precondition_failed.html
ErrorDocument 414 /error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html
ErrorDocument 415 /error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html
ErrorDocument 501 /error_docs/not_implemented.html
ErrorDocument 502 /error_docs/bad_gateway.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error_docs/maintenance.html

    Include "/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/file_sharing.conf*"



</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What is the http code response from server? You can check it in Firebug on "Net" tab.
2. Check that www.mydomain.com resolves to same IP as mydomain.com (nslookup www.mydomain.com)
3. check that apache's config is applied: apachectl -S / apache2ctl -S | grep www.mydomain.com

Comment: NSLookup queries for mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com resolved to the same (correct) IP.  However, checking the net response told me that the remote IP was different than expected.  Turns out I had fixed it via the URL rewrite and didn't realize it.  I tried it from my home as opposed to my office and it worked fine.  Whereas before implementing the URL rewrite, it did not work from my home.  The reason the http response from my browser was different was that my local hosts file had an entry for www resolving to an old box from early development.  Thanks for the help!